# Restriction input queu size at Micronaut(Netty)

Tags: java, netty, micronaut

When the application is started but not yet warmed(Jit need time), it cannot process the expected RPS.
The problem is in the incoming queue. As the IO thread continues to process requests, there are many requests in the queue that the GC cannot clean up. After the overflow of the Survived generation, GC starts perfom major pause, which slows down the execution of requests even more and after some time the application falls on the OOM.
My application have self warmed readnessProbe (3k random request).

I try to configure count of thread and queue size:
application.yml

```
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8080
    netty:
      parent:
        threads: 2
      worker:
        threads: 2
  executors:
    io:
      n-threads: 1
      parallelism: 1
      type: FIXED
    scheduled:
      n-threads: 1
      parallelism: 1
      corePoolSize: 1
```

And some props

```
    System.setProperty("io.netty.eventLoop.maxPendingTasks", "16")
    System.setProperty("io.netty.eventexecutor.maxPendingTasks", "16")
    System.setProperty("io.netty.eventLoopThreads", "1")
```

But the queue keeps filling up:
[image: RPS]
[image: Memory]
[image: JProfiler]

i want to find somw way to restriction input queu size at Micronaut, so that the application does not failed  under high load